# How to create new functions on laptop keyboard?

Tags: laptop, windows-8.1, keyboard, mouse

I got a new laptop, a Toshiba Portege Z30-A. It has a pointing stick (the dot in the middle, also called TrackPoint on Lenovo laptops) and it has the left and right click buttons. My old laptop used to have three buttons, left and right click buttons as well as a middle button which you could hold down and use the pointing stick to scroll up and down. Is it possible to program my right click button so that if I hold it down and move the pointing stick, I can scroll up and down? (Right now I'm using arrow keys or pg up/down, which are far from home row).

Comment: Might be possible if something like AutoHotkey is able to detect the state of the pointing stick.